# Build a wav file with multiple frequencies

Tags: node.js, wav

We would like to build a wav file with multiple frequencies for a specified duration for each frequency.

I'll try to explain the use case

Say we need to build a wav file with frequency ranging from 150MHz to 200MHz for the first 5 secs( the whole wave file from frequency 150MHz, 150.1MHz, 150.2MHz, etc up to 200MHz should end in 5 secs time)
The next 10 secs should be from 200MHz to 300MHz
The next 15 secs should be from 300MHz to 400MHz
Once all the 3 wav files are generated, we need to combine/concat all these 3 into a single wav file of 30 secs (5+10+15)

Can anyone please let us know how can we achieve this.

My Code :

```
//https://www.npmjs.com/package/tonegenerator

var tone = require('tonegenerator');
var header = require('waveheader');
var fs = require('fs');

var file = fs.createWriteStream('16bit_400_600.wav')
var t =[];

var first = tone({ freq: 4000000, lengthInSecs: 0.01, volume: tone.MAX_16,  rate: 44100000,  shape: 'sine' })

for(var i = 4000000.1; i <6000000.1; i+=0.1) {
    
var j = tone({ freq: i.toFixed(1), lengthInSecs: 0.01, volume: tone.MAX_16,  rate: 44100000,  shape: 'sine' })
//var j = tone({ freq: 428, lengthInSecs: 5, volume: tone.MAX_16,  rate: 44100,  shape: 'sine' })

    // res = res.concat(j);

    //first.concat(j);
    
    t.push(j)

    //console.info(i.toFixed(1));
}

res = first.concat(...t);

 
file.write(header(res.length * 2, {
  bitDepth: 16
}))
 
var data = Int16Array.from(res)
 
var size = data.length * 2 // 2 bytes per sample
if (Buffer.allocUnsafe) { 
  buffer = Buffer.allocUnsafe(size)
} else {
  buffer = new Buffer(size)
}
 
data.forEach(function (value, index) {
  buffer.writeInt16LE(value, index * 2)
})
 
file.write(buffer)
file.end()
```

Comment: You need two for loops before the the tone is pushed to sample and when you increment  use the toFixed with ParseFloat, was able to replicate the same in my local machine.

Comment: Hi Bharath, So kind for your response. The code which i mentioned is a working code for the frequency level 400Hz,500Hz and so on. But i need the frequency level of 400MHz (ie, 400*1000000 = 400,000000). So if you have any idea regarding with the requirement kindly share that. Thanks in advance.....

Answer (score 0):

Issue is with the rate value that is sent to the tone function, in the [tonegenerator index.js file](https://github.com/karlwestin/node-tonegenerator/blob/master/index.js), we can see that

```js
var cycle = Math.floor(rate/freq);
var samplesLeft = lengthInSecs * rate;
var cycles = samplesLeft/cycle;
```

Since the rate is low compared to frequency the cycle becomes zero when the Math.floor() function is called.
Cycles can't be calculated hence the program hangs.

Adjust the rate as per frequency so the cycle variable is not zero and some postive value.

### Edit

I'm not sure about he tone logic but this is how i cleaned your code.

```js
const tone = require('tonegenerator');
const header = require('waveheader');
const {createWriteStream} = require('fs');

let samples = [];

const makeChannel = (freq, lengthInSecs) => {
    let channel = tone({ freq: freq, lengthInSecs: lengthInSecs, volume: tone.MAX_16, rate: 44100,  shape: 'sine' });
    for (var i = 0; i < channel.length; i++) {
        samples.push(channel[i])
    }
};

let start = 150;
let end = 200;
const increment = 0.1;

for (let index = parseFloat(start); index <= parseFloat(end); index = parseFloat((index + increment).toFixed(1))) {
    makeChannel(index, 0.01);
}

start = 200;
end = 300;

for (let index = parseFloat(start); index <= parseFloat(end); index = parseFloat((index + increment).toFixed(1))) {
    makeChannel(index, 0.01);
}

start = 300;
end = 400;

for (let index = parseFloat(start); index <= parseFloat(end); index = parseFloat((index + increment).toFixed(1))) {
    makeChannel(index, 0.015);
}

let file = createWriteStream('16bit-stereo_01.wav');

file.write(header(samples.length * 2, {
    channels: 2,
    bitDepth: 16
}));

const data = Int16Array.from(samples);

const size = data.length * 2;

const buffer = new Buffer.alloc(size);

data.forEach((value, index) => {
    buffer.writeInt16LE(value, index * 2)
});

file.write(buffer);
file.end();
```

Comment: Hi Bharath, I did what you mentioned in code. But still I am not getting the exact output. I will add the updated lines to my code. Can you please check that. Since i am new to the codding world as well as Node Js. So , I hope you understand my situation.......

Comment: Make sure the rate and frequency ratio is over 100 which works for lower Hz

Comment: Hi Bharath. Thank you for your response and  engaging some time for this work. But the requirement from the client side is to develop the wav file of MHz frequencies wav. And it should have some duration (Like :[ 150Mhz - 200 Mhz  duration : 10Sec], [200Mhz - 250Mhz duration: 5 sec, ......] ).So I am researching for this task.......

Comment: Do let me know if you are able to fix the tone generation part. Would like to understand where I missed it. I have gut feeling its something to do with tone generation with respect to the rate and frequency.